# Angular 2 apache .htaccess file 404 on subpages

Tags: php, angular, apache, .htaccess, angular-routing

I have successfully installed and ran Angular 2 app on my apache server, I am able to navigate through the pages via `[routerLink]="['/register']"`

However when I refresh the page I get a 404 error on the register page. Is there something wrong with my rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Also here is my apache VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/front/dist/browser
    <Directory /var/www/html/front>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Might help to show the webserver logs, or the verbatim URL you requested.

Comment: requesting URL example.com/register I get this error: The requested URL /register was not found on this server.

Comment: GET /register HTTP/1.1" 404 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.
3396.99 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it by redirecting 404 Error to your index.html

– In Apache Server hosting, edit Apache configuration:

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

– Add ErrorDocument 404 like this:
my index.html is found in /var/www/html/vas/index.html

– Full file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# redirect 404 to index page
ErrorDocument 404 /vas/index.html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

– Restart Apache server by cmd sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As per I understand, your rewrite rules don't seem correct to me..

You are saying if the requested document is not a file **AND** not a Directory **AND** I guess not the index page then redirect to `index.html` and what if they are?? And why don't you want to go to the index page? I believe `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index` means you don't want to go to index.

I don't know what is your requirement but for a simplistic reqirement I use:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]   # don't redirect for files which phycically exit
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  # don't redirect for directories
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  # if the above condition(s) satisfy then do nothing
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [NC,L] # for everything else, redirect to index.html
```

Comment: still did not work, I got a 404 error when refreshing the page `The requested URL /search/professionals was not found on this server.`

Comment: Yes it works when I goto example.com and when I click on links in my navigation via [routerLink]="['/register']" it also works, but when I am on example.com/register and refresh the page I get a 404 error, but not when I goto example.com/register via [routerLink]="['/register']" it works, but not when I refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Check this:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1630

Ref:https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a ***.htaccess*** file on the root of your application with the below rules,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```